# how can I build this update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have two values from `URL`. This is those,

```
$_GET['a'] // this variable has a email address
$_GET['b'] // this variable has a code to activate my account.
```

I am trying to create UPDATE query using these two values, but problem is these two values belong to two different tables. `email` has in contact table and `active` column has in user table.

This is my code so far:

```
$q = "UPDATE tutors SET active = NULL 
      WHERE (active='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['z']) . "') 
      LIMIT 1";
```

This code is working for me. but I need to check both values in `WHERE` clause. Can anybody help me to build this query?

**UPDATE :**

```
$q = "UPDATE tutors t, contact c SET t.active = NULL 
      WHERE t.active = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['z']) . "' 
          AND c.email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['y']) . "' 
          AND t.contact_id = c.contact_id
      LIMIT 1";
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your link between `tutors` and `contact`? I'm guessing there are IDs somewhere?

Comment: So you are trying to update the `tutors` table, based on values in the `users` and `contacts` table??

Comment: Sorry, a little confused now.  Can you confirm which tables you have and what the link is between them. For example `tutors` and `users`, tutors has a `user_id` field

Comment: yes... `tutors` table have `tutor_id` and `contact_id`

Comment: `contact` table have `contact_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At a guess**: something like this would work if your `tutors` and `contacts` are linked via a `contact_id` in the `tutors` table.

```
<?php
$q = "UPDATE tutors T, contacts C SET T.active = NULL 
WHERE T.active = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['z']) . "' 
AND C.email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['a']) . "' 
AND T.contact_id = C.contact_id"
```

but... I would need more information about your database schema to make this a more precise answer.

Comment: I added limit clause to your answer then there is an error - `MySQL Error: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT`

Comment: You wouldn't normally use a LIMIT with an UPDATE.  You can with row counts, usually you would UPDATE a single or multiple records based on the WHERE clauses

Comment: @UselessIntern I tried it with `inner join` but not working it. see my updated query, it also not working for me.

Comment: Join shouldn't be necessary although you could do it with one.  The query I posted should work if  my assumptions match TNK's database. You would just change the C.id to C.contact_id

Comment: I removed `limit` clause from my query then its working for me. doesn't it matter remove limit clause?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter. If this query is working for you then its working. You don't need to use LIMIT, and as I mentioned in the other comment, its unusual to use it in UPDATE anyway.

Comment: @fullybaked: yeah I just ran the query after fixing that typo in MySql with junk values and it updated it.

Comment: @UselessIntern, noted. When I answered the field names weren't in the question. I've edited my answer to ensure others don't fall into that trap. :)